# Exception Handled this was Nullptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, nullpointerexception, unhandled-exception, nullptr

[image]

I've been working on this assignment, and been running into this bug I haven't been able to fix for hours. It's saying unhandled exception thrown, read access violation. I heard you're not suppose to deference nullptrs, however I don't believe that's what I'm doing.

```cpp
void Linkedlist::insertnode(string key, string value) {
    Node* newNode;                      //This points to the following node
    Node* cursor;                       //This will traverse through list
    newNode = new Node;                 //create a new node
    newNode->data = new HashEntry(key, value);              //Initialize the data 
    newNode->next = nullptr;            //Leave the pointer for the node following after empty at inception;
    if (!head) {
        head = newNode;                 //if head is empty, this will make the first user input the head
        return;
    }
    
    else {
        cursor = head;
        while (cursor->next)
            ;       
        //We'll traverse list to add newNode to tail
        cursor->next = newNode;     //for now the order doesn't matter since they're strings so we add new cluster to tail
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You are most likely dereferencing it through `->`.

Comment: Where is `head` initialized?

Comment: `while (cursor->next);` is an infinite loop.

Comment: The only `this` that can be null there is the `Linkedlist`'s own. How are you creating this instance?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post the text. (And it *is* the `Linkedlist` instance's `this` that is null. You're using an invalid `Linkedlist*` somewhere. You have probably become stuck by assuming that the cause of a problem is necessarily near the point where you discover it.)

Comment: Code should probably be

 while (cursor->next)
            cursor = cursor->next;

Answer (score 0):

"read access violation" is most likely an uninitialized variable. It happens when you try to access data from memory outside your program memory. This is a protection mechanism of your system to prevent you from overwriting data you shouldn't.

Therefore I'd recommend checking your definition of the class `HashEntry` as well as the definition of the Pointer `head` which isn't in your posted code.

What also came in my view is your infinite loop `while (cursor->next);`

I get what you're trying to do - iterate over the elements until you're at the end of the list. But you have to use an iterator:

```
Node* iterator = cursor;
while (iterator)
{
  iterator = iterator->next;
}
```